FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Windows\System32\EGL.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax
I'm working on a Windows machine and I'm trying to load the EGL.dll using ctypes in Python, but I'm encountering a FileNotFoundError. I have downloaded the EGL.dll file and placed it in the C:\Windows\System32 directory. However, when I run my code, I receive the following error:
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Windows\System32\EGL.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tqdm
import argparse
from ctypes import CDLL
from _ctypes import LoadLibrary


# Custom function to load DLLs on Windows
def load_dll(path: str) -> CDLL:
    if path == "" or path is None:
        raise TypeError("Please provide a valid path")
    handle = LoadLibrary(path)
    return CDLL(name=path, handle=handle) if handle != 0 else handle


# Specify the full path to the EGL.dll
dll_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\EGL.dll"

# Load the DLL using the custom function
load_dll(dll_path)

# Set the environment variable for OpenGL to use EGL
os.environ['PYOPENGL_PLATFORM'] = 'egl'

# Add the root directory of the project to the Python path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent))

# Add the tokenhmr module to the Python path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent))

from lib.models import load_tokenhmr
from lib.utils import recursive_to
from lib.datasets.vitdet_dataset import ViTDetDataset, DEFAULT_MEAN, DEFAULT_STD
from lib.utils.renderer import Renderer, cam_crop_to_full

LIGHT_BLUE = (0.65098039, 0.74117647, 0.85882353)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='TokenHMR demo code')
    parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', type=str, default='', help='Path to pretrained model checkpoint')
    parser.add_argument('--model_config', type=str, default='model_config.yaml', help='Path to model config file')
    parser.add_argument('--img_folder', type=str, default='example_data/images', help='Folder with input images')
    parser.add_argument('--out_folder', type=str, default='demo_out', help='Output folder to save rendered results')
    parser.add_argument('--side_view', dest='side_view', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='If set, render side view also')
    parser.add_argument('--full_frame', dest='full_frame', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='If set, render all people together also')
    parser.add_argument('--save_mesh', dest='save_mesh', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='If set, save meshes to disk also')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=1, help='Batch size for inference/fitting')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    model, model_cfg = load_tokenhmr(checkpoint_path=args.checkpoint,
                                     model_cfg=args.model_config,
                                     is_train_state=False, is_demo=True)

    # Setup model
    device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
    model = model.to(device)
    model.eval()

    # Load detector
    from detectron2.detectron2.engine.defaults import DefaultPredictor
    from lib.utils.utils_detectron2 import DefaultPredictor_Lazy
    from detectron2.detectron2.config import LazyConfig
    import lib
    cfg_path = Path(lib.__file__).parent / 'configs' / 'cascade_mask_rcnn_vitdet_h_75ep.py'
    detectron2_cfg = LazyConfig.load(str(cfg_path))
    detectron2_cfg.train.init_checkpoint = "https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/ViTDet/COCO/cascade_mask_rcnn_vitdet_h/f328730692/model_final_f05665.pkl"
    for i in range(3):
        detectron2_cfg.model.roi_heads.box_predictors[i].test_score_thresh = 0.25
    detector = DefaultPredictor_Lazy(detectron2_cfg)

    # Setup the renderer
    renderer = Renderer(model_cfg, faces=model.smpl.faces)

    # Make output directory if it does not exist
    os.makedirs(args.out_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Iterate over all images in folder
    for img_path in tqdm.tqdm(sorted(Path(args.img_folder).glob('*'))):
        print(f'Processing {img_path}..')
        img_cv2 = cv2.imread(str(img_path))

        # Detect humans in image
        det_out = detector(img_cv2)
        det_instances = det_out['instances']
        valid_idx = (det_instances.pred_classes == 0) & (det_instances.scores > 0.5)
        boxes = det_instances.pred_boxes.tensor[valid_idx].cpu().numpy()

        # Run on all detected humans
        dataset = ViTDetDataset(model_cfg, img_cv2, boxes)
        dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

        all_verts = []
        all_cam_t = []

        for batch in dataloader:
            batch = recursive_to(batch, device)
            with torch.no_grad():
                out = model(batch)

            pred_cam = out['pred_cam']
            box_center = batch["box_center"].float()
            box_size = batch["box_size"].float()
            img_size = batch["img_size"].float()
            scaled_focal_length = model_cfg.EXTRA.FOCAL_LENGTH / model_cfg.MODEL.IMAGE_SIZE * img_size.max()
            pred_cam_t_full = cam_crop_to_full(pred_cam, box_center, box_size, img_size,
                                               scaled_focal_length).detach().cpu().numpy()

            # Render the result
            batch_size = batch['img'].shape[0]
            for n in range(batch_size):
                # Get filename from path img_path
                img_fn, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(img_path))
                person_id = int(batch['personid'][n])
                white_img = (torch.ones_like(batch['img'][n]).cpu() - DEFAULT_MEAN[:, None, None] / 255) / (
                            DEFAULT_STD[:, None, None] / 255)
                input_patch = batch['img'][n].cpu() * (DEFAULT_STD[:, None, None] / 255) + (
                            DEFAULT_MEAN[:, None, None] / 255)
                input_patch = input_patch.permute(1, 2, 0).numpy()

                regression_img = renderer(out['pred_vertices'][n].detach().cpu().numpy(),
                                          out['pred_cam_t'][n].detach().cpu().numpy(),
                                          batch['img'][n],
                                          mesh_base_color=LIGHT_BLUE,
                                          scene_bg_color=(1, 1, 1),
                                          )

                if args.side_view:
                    side_img = renderer(out['pred_vertices'][n].detach().cpu().numpy(),
                                        out['pred_cam_t'][n].detach().cpu().numpy(),
                                        white_img,
                                        mesh_base_color=LIGHT_BLUE,
                                        scene_bg_color=(1, 1, 1),
                                        side_view=True)
                    final_img = np.concatenate([input_patch, regression_img, side_img], axis=1)
                else:
                    final_img = np.concatenate([input_patch, regression_img], axis=1)

                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(args.out_folder, f'{img_fn}_{person_id}.png'), 255 * final_img[:, :, ::-1])

                # Add all verts and cams to list
                verts = out['pred_vertices'][n].detach().cpu().numpy()
                cam_t = pred_cam_t_full[n]
                all_verts.append(verts)
                all_cam_t.append(cam_t)

                # Save all meshes to disk
                if args.save_mesh:
                    camera_translation = cam_t.copy()
                    tmesh = renderer.vertices_to_trimesh(verts, camera_translation, LIGHT_BLUE)
                    tmesh.export(os.path.join(args.out_folder, f'{img_fn}_{person_id}.obj'))

        # Render front view
        if args.full_frame and len(all_verts) > 0:
            misc_args = dict(
                mesh_base_color=LIGHT_BLUE,
                scene_bg_color=(1, 1, 1),
                focal_length=scaled_focal_length,
            )
            cam_view = renderer.render_rgba_multiple(all_verts, cam_t=all_cam_t, render_res=img_size[n], **misc_args)

            # Overlay image
            input_img = img_cv2.astype(np.float32)[:, :, ::-1] / 255.0
            input_img = np.concatenate([input_img, np.ones_like(input_img[:, :, :1])], axis=2)  # Add alpha channel
            input_img_overlay = input_img[:, :, :3] * (1 - cam_view[:, :, 3:]) + cam_view[:, :, :3] * cam_view[:, :, 3:]

            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(args.out_folder, f'{img_fn}_all.png'), 255 * input_img_overlay[:, :, ::-1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Despite passing the correct path, I'm still getting the error. I've also ensured that the DLL is indeed located in the specified directory.
Could anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how I might resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:
I tried loading the EGL.dll using the ctypes library in Python. Specifically, I used a custom function to load the DLL by passing the full path (C:\Windows\System32\EGL.dll) to the LoadLibrary function from _ctypes, and then created a CDLL instance with it.
What I Expected:
I expected the DLL to load successfully without any errors since the file is located in the specified path.
What Actually Happened:
Instead of loading successfully, I encountered a FileNotFoundError, indicating that the module could not be found or one of its dependencies might be missing. The error message suggests using the full path with the constructor syntax, which I already did. Despite this, the issue persists.

You need to try and find out what dependent file it is trying to access. This information should be provided at the product website.

"or one of its dependencies might be missing".  Run a utility like depends or dumpbin on the DLL to see what dependencies it requires.  Since your full path appears to be correct, it has to be a missing dependency.

[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer).
